# Prove that : $\sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=0}\varphi^{k}(0)$ are doesn't defines a distribution .

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

I need prove the following extention doesn't defines a distribution on $\mathbb{R}$
$$\sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=0}\varphi^{k}(0)~~~,~~~\varphi\in D(\mathbb{R})$$
My attempts :

I will prove the above serie are not convergent so I use :

$$\varphi(x)=e^{x}\psi(x)$$

Where $\psi\in D(\mathbb{R})$ and $\psi(x)=1$ if $x\in [-a;a]$ and $\psi(x)=0$ otherwise

So we find : $\varphi^{k}(0)=1$ this mean that the sum are not convergence

---

Are my Steps correct ?

Is there another ideas ?

Comment: Can't be correct. $\psi$ is not even continuous

Comment: @meowdog I can define this $\psi$ at a point for example $\psi(x)=0$ when $x=0$ and $\psi(x)=0$ otherwise

Comment: But isn't a test function supposed to be in $C_0^\infty$?

Comment: You need to remove the "$\psi(x)=0$ otherwise" and it will be correct. $\psi$ must be smooth on the whole of $\Bbb{R}$ and $0$ outside of an interval.

Comment: @reuns how I can difined $\varphi$

Answer (score 1):

With $$\rho(x)= e^{-1/(1-x^2)} 1_{|x|<1}, \qquad C=\int_\Bbb{R} \rho(x)dx$$
$\rho$ is smooth on $\Bbb{R}$ and supported on $[-1,1]$.
then $$\psi(x)= \frac1C \int_{-3}^3 \rho(x-y)dy$$
is smooth on $\Bbb{R}$, supported on $[-4,4]$, and constant $=1$ on $[-2,2]$.

So $$\varphi(x)= e^x \psi(x)$$ works, it is smooth on $\Bbb{R}$, supported on $[-4,4]$, and $$\varphi^{(k)}(0)=1$$
which proves that $$\phi \mapsto \sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=0}\phi^{k}(0)$$ is not a distribution.